# Userform QueryClose Will only Work Once

Tags: vba, excel

My Current Issue is that once the Query Close is ran by hitting the top right X button and calls for the parameters i had set and try to do it again the X Button is disabled.

I Have a Userform that Uses a Query Close Code Shown Below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
    MainMenuUserform.Hide
    CloseForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

The Form This Calls Asks the User if they Would like to save changes and requests a "Yes" or "No" with 2 Buttons that are set up working with no problems and I have set the QueryClose on that form (By Hitting the X Button On Userform)
to send you back to the Main userform.

```
Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, ClsoeMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
    CloseForm.Hide
    MainMenuUserform.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the Form

[image]

The Problem I am having is that once the Queryclose is ran it will not call for it again. Making the X Button on the Main Userform Disabled. As well as the Close Form

I am using the [userform.Hide] due to when i would use [Unload Userform] Command and would call for that userform to show again it would give me the "Userform Already Displayed" Error.

Maybe I am Making a simple Task too Difficult.

I would appreciate the Help and Feedback.  Thank You,

Main Form

[Main Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFL47.png)

Comment: You have a typo `ClsoeMode`... I wouldn't be sure if that solves the problem

Comment: @sancho.s nope. The argument name makes no difference, only the type and position; the handler gets invoked either way.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - But the value of `CloseMode` may not be read properly... I guess (although the fact the OP sees the Froms hiding/showing probably means that the `If` condition is anyway evaluated to `True`).

Comment: @sancho.s true, and correct - except the object that's shown from `CloseForm` is not the same instance that brought `CloseForm` into view - sure both are the form's *default instance*, but once `QueryClose` runs to completion (after the modal `CloseMode` form closes), because OP isn't setting `Cancel` to `True`, the instance is effectively destroyed, so the 2nd `Show` is just a "new" default instance. The robust solution is to stop using default instances and pull the logic out of the forms and into a presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only running once, because once `CloseForm.Show` returns, the handler exits and the object is destroyed, because you never *cancelled* the closing:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
        CloseForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Notice I replaced `MainMenuUserform` with `Me`. [This article of mine](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) goes in-depth about the reasoning. Shortly put, you're referring to the form's *default instance*, which is inevitably going to cause problems.

---

FWIW that `CloseForm` could very well be a simple `MsgBox`, given `vbYesNo` buttons: that would eliminate the need to have forms interacting with each others.

If you're willing to do things right, then you'll want to implement a proper dialog interface - this would be the code-behind for that yes/no form:

```
Option Explicit
Private mDialogResult As VbMsgBoxResult

Public Property Get DialogResult() As VbMsgBoxResult
    DialogResult = mDialogResult
End Property

Private Sub YesButton_Click()
    mDialogResult = vbYes
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub NoButton_Click()
    mDialogResult = vbNo
    Me.Hide
End Sub    

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Notice it isn't coupled with the other form in any way, shape or form; it doesn't know what to save either, nor what to do with the dialog result. Its job is to prompt the user with a message, and return a result to the caller.

This would be the logic in the `MenuMenuUserForm` code-behind:

```
Option Explicit
Private mCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = mCancelled
End Propety

Private Sub PromptToSaveChanges()
    With New CloseForm
        .Show
        mCancelled = (.DialogResult = vbNo)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    PromptToSaveChanges
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        PromptToSaveChanges
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, I don't have your full context, so I'm making these assumptions:

- Main form has an [OK] button that doesn't prompt to save any changes. If the form is closed with that button, changes are saved.
- Main form has a [Cancel] button that works exactly the same as "x-ing out" of the form; user is prompted, and changes are saved or discarded accordingly.
- Prompt result is either `vbYes` or `vbNo`; user has no opportunity to back out and cancel the closing at that point (i.e. return `vbCancel` and skip the `Me.Hide`)

So the calling code would look like this:

```
With New MainMenuUserForm
    .Show
    If Not .IsCancelled Then
        ' save changes... whatever that means
    End If
End With
```

Notice at no point in time any form's default instance gets displayed: it's always a `New` instance. This is what ensures no state gets lost in global scope, and accidentally discarded by a self-destructing object.

Comment: i apologize for not having a image of my main form , i have added it sadly i do not have a OK button or Cancel  on it, I am new to VBA and working with userforms so when i had originally started i set the Closeform Userform as to not clutter the first Userform I did not know the calling of userforms would in end discard objects.

Comment: @ErickU9314 I'd warmly recommend you only use a UserForm when you have to - that prompt dialog could very well and easily be replaced with a simple `MsgBox` function call. The rule of thumb, is that a form shouldn't need to be aware of any other forms - instead you'd have a "presenter" (class or procedure, doesn't matter) responsible for running the show. Adopting this methodology early on will avoid many headaches down the road!

Comment: Thank You for the Help Mat, this does help me out tremendously with certain issues i have been having. I will replace the CloseForm Userform with the MSG Box as you have said.   Thank You for your Help Mat.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/queryclose-event), you need to cancel the `QueryClose` event.

Perhaps you'd also rather use `Me` instead of the name, and `Hide`/`Show` in a proper order.

```
' In MainMenuUserform
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = 1
        Me.Hide
        CloseForm.Show
    End If
End Sub

' In CloseForm
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Me.Hide
        MainMenuUserform.Show
        Me.Unload
    End If
End Sub
```

Probably the `If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then ...` are not needed.

I am under Ubuntu, so I cannot test it.